# Why didn't show element inside the <div> if a value is selected in drop down box?

Tags: jquery, html

I just wonder why the element inside the  didn't show up if a value is selected in drop drown box?But it is work fine in JSFiddle :[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ca4Es/)

Below show how my HTML code and Jquery script work in my own system:

```
<tr>
                <th class="title">Registration</th>
                <td> : </td>
                <th><select name="reg" id="registration">
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    </select>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <div id="opt" style="display:none;">
            <tr>
                <th class="title">Participant</th>
                <td> : </td>
                <th><input type="text" name="participant"></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th class="title">Payment Amount</th>
                <td> : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th class="title">Payment Method</th>
                <td> : </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="CC">Credit Card
                <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="Counter">Counter
                </td>
            </tr>
            </div><!--end of the opt-->
```

Jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#registration").change(function(){
 if($(this).val()=="Yes"){
            $("#opt").show();
       }else {
        $("#opt").hide();   
       }

 });      
}); 

   </script>
```

The sample output as below:
       [image]

Supposed when the value No is selected,it will not showing anything,

Comment: your html is invalid, table cannot have `div` as a child

Comment: Try using `tbody` instead if `div` as `#opt` element

Comment: also check the browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: You mean change <div id="opt"> in html into <tbody>??

Comment: yes `<div id="opt">` to `<tbody id="opt">`

Comment: your code is working fine everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is the completed markup for your table, you could remove the `#opt` element entirely and do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#registration").change(function(){
 if($(this).val()=="Yes"){
            $("tr + tr").show();
       }else {
        $("tr + tr").hide();   
       }

 });      
}); 
</script>
```

Otherwise, the suggestion of leveraging `<tbody` is a good one:

```
    <tr>
            <th class="title">Registration</th>
            <td> : </td>
            <th><select name="reg" id="registration">
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tbodyid="opt" style="display:none;">
        <tr>
            <th class="title">Participant</th>
            <td> : </td>
            <th><input type="text" name="participant"></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class="title">Payment Amount</th>
            <td> : </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th class="title">Payment Method</th>
            <td> : </td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="CC">Credit Card
            <input type="radio" name="pay_method" value="Counter">Counter
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody><!--end of the opt-->

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#registration").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="Yes"){
            $("#opt").show();
       }else {
        $("#opt").hide();   
       }

  });      
 }); 
</script>
```